# MC and MCedit take long time to start

Tags: mc, strace

I recently discovered that my MidnightCommander takes around 40 seconds for every startup and the same goes for McEdit.

I access my machine only via ssh and of course I'm not logging in as root, only to prevent the questions.

I did an strace and it puts out two system calls that take around 20 seconds:

`poll([{fd =3, events=POLLIN}], 1, -1) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLIN}])
select(5, [4], NULL, NULL, NULL) = 1 (in [4])`

Unfortunately I don't have the heck of a clue what these calls are, any hints or help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Update:
If I do a sudo mc it works as usual, only with my accout it does take that long.

Solution:
The solution is simple, I had X11 forwarding in Putty enabled, after deactivating it everything works like a charm. Strange, but anyway, it works again.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You should ask them about this via the mail list or a bug report.  I've been using mc (but never the internal editor) constantly, everywhere I work, for years and years, and never seen it take more than a second (two would indicate a very busy machine) even remotely on a wimpy little system.  Of course first make sure the system isn't constantly busy...

Comment: Thanks, I will if no solution pops up. At least I know it's not about the busyness, the machine has way enough resources left for this little task!

Comment: You need to scroll back in the trace and find what is opened on that file descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar problem. Check if your hostname is properly resolved to IP address. If not, try to add your hostname to /etc/hosts eg.:

> 127.0.0.2 myhostname myhostname.mydomain

Comment: I'm a bit confused, the /etc/hosts says `127.0.1.1 myhost` Can this be right? Sounds wrong to me, but I don't know.

Comment: It's ok. loopback has address network 127.0.0.0/8

Comment: Alright, so this is not the solution. I updated the question because I discovered that everything is fine if I call mc via sudo, any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your strace on pastebin? And another `strace` with `-c`

Comment: `strace -c`: http://pastebin.com/SxQUrXP2 `strace`:http://pastebin.com/pFbiWGYC

Comment: any idea if I cant change the /etc/hosts?

Comment: oh, this may be feature breaking but worked here `alias mc='TERM=linux mc'`

Comment: Had this happen to me with a Raspberry Pi after install Pi-Hole DNS. Editing hosts corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem when X forwarding is on, but X server is not running on my client. You have to use the `-X` or `--no-x11` command line parameter with `mc` to prevent waiting for a timeout (which may be only 2 seconds, not 40).